# Command Line Batch Script

Tags: zip

i use this script to compress all .txt and .cpi files into the backup folder in separated files with 7zip. After the files are zipped i delete the original files. However this script has a logical flaw. Lets say if the 7zip program fails to run, the files will also get deleted. How can i change the script so that it should not delete the files if they don't get zipped first. Also how can i change this script so it zips files that are older than 7 days? Thanks for your help.
@echo off
setlocal

```
set _source=C:\test7zip\bak    
set _dest=C:\test7zip\bak    
set _wrpath=C:\Program Files\7-Zip        
if NOT EXIST %_dest% md %_dest%    
for %%I in (%_source%\*.txt,%_source%\*.cpi) do "%_wrpath%\7z" a "%_dest%\%%~nI.7z" "%%I" & del "%%I"
```

pause

Answer (score 0):

You seem to now more than me but i might be able to help....

Inside the 7zip you could a batch file that when unzipped changes a system varible...
The batch file (that you have already done) that unzips the files could check to see if variable is true before delete the files .... or something.?

Hope that helps in anyway?

For the zipping of the files witch are a certain days old... you could have a batch file that has a 7 day timer and that after the time is up it zips the certain directory of files into 7zip?

That's all i could help you with.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check or test your code thoroughly, but I did notice this right away. The "&" in the last line of your script creates a conditional command that will always execute the second command, regardless whether the 1st fails or succeeds. Change it to && to create a conditional command where the 2nd command only executes upon successful completion of the 1st, like this:

> for %%I in (%_source%*.txt,%_source%*.cpi) do "%_wrpath%\7z" a "%_dest%\%%~nI.7z" "%%I" && del "%%I"

For including files older than 7 days, use the below changes to move them to a temp directory before zipping them:

```
set _source=C:\test7zip\bak 
set _dest=C:\test7zip\bak 
set _temp1=C:\test7zip\temp1

set _wrpath=C:\Program Files\7-Zip        
if NOT EXIST %_dest% md %_dest% 
forfiles /P %_source% /S /M *.txt /D -7 /C "cmd /c move @file %_temp1%"
forfiles /P %_source% /S /M *.cpi /D -7 /C "cmd /c move @file %_temp1%" 
for %%I in (%_temp1%\*.txt,%_temp1%\*.cpi) do "%_wrpath%\7z" a "%_dest%\%%~nI.7z" "%%I" && del "%%I"
```